# MVC Readonly Display For Value

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have an MVC Form in which I would to display some non editable values.

```
<form asp-action="AuthorizeTransaction" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="To"></label>
        <input asp-for="To" class="form-control" />
        <label asp-for="Amount"></label>
        <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
        <label asp-for="Currency"></label>
        <input asp-for="Currency" class="form-control" />
        <label asp-for="Description"></label>
        <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I know I probably can make the inputs readonly, but I would like to know if there is a way to display form values without using a textbox and still have the values posted. I would like to do something like this:

```
<label asp-for="Amount"></label>
<display asp-for"Amount"></display>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: `<display asp-for"Amount"></display>` is not known in .NET Core. Also note that `@Html.DisplayFor()` helper only displays the value, you need hidden fields to postback, so that you can try custom tag helper which renders both value and hidden field simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to display some values as non editable. So either you can use property like readonly or you can use 
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property) an html helper from mvc to make something read only. It will render as a label in the form

Comment: If I use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property)` Will this automatically send then with my form or do I still need to back this with a hidden property

Comment: Yes. You need the hidden field for sending the data from ui to Controller